Как сделать так, чтобы после того, как пользователь пишет текст на данном блоке, он записывался в переменную и отправлялся другому пользователю?
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "btn1":
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('⬅️Назад', callback_data='btn3')
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Введите текст',      
                              reply_markup=markup)```

